# python traceback - how to raise an exception and keep the stack

Tags: python, stack-trace

I have 2 modules:

## a.py:

```
import b
import traceback
try:
    print b.get_val(1)
except Exception as ex:
    traceback.print_stack()
    print ex
```

The problem is that the stack trace does not say whick line of b.py raised the exception. It also happens if there is an actual run time error.
Any ideas how to display the whole stack?

## b.py

```
def get_val(val):
    print 'hi'
    raise Exception('Bad value')
```

Comment: It's python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `traceback.print_exc()` instead of `traceback.print_stack()`

`traceback.print_stack()` output:

```
hi
  File "a.py", line 6, in <module>
    traceback.print_stack()
Bad value
```

`traceback.print_exc()` output:

```
hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 4, in <module>
    print b.get_val(1)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\SOF\b.py", line 3, in get_val
    raise Exception('Bad value')
Exception: Bad value
Bad value
```

Comment: Good answer.  I also want to mention exception chaining [(PEP 3134)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/) as a bit of carrot for Python 3 here.